# CakePHP test - unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cakephp

I am new to testing or so called unit testing. i am on the verge of finishing a web application. i wanna know is unit testing important. and how does it help ?

as i have never written a test. can i get reference to some kinda guide or tutoriials regarding to writing test ?

i am using cakephp framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://debuggable.com/posts/unit-testing-in-cakephp-part-1---introduction-to-unit-testing:48102610-c5d0-4398-a010-76974834cda3) is a great introduction to unit testing and how to do it with CakePHP.

Comment: @Harsha: Please mark my answer as correct if you are satisfied with it. Thanks!